# How do I use more than one character for the bounds of an integral?

Tags: math-mode

When I write latex like

```
Evaluate $\int_4^16 x\ dx$. \\
```

I expect to get an integral like

[image: Good]

but instead I get

[image: Bad]

How do I get the integral I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use curly braces to enclose the bounds, like so:

```
Evaluate $\int_{4}^{16} x\ dx$. \\
```

Comment: Note there is nothing specific about integrals or superscripts here. LaTeX arguments should always be in `{}` although it is sometimes safe to omit the `{}` if the argument is a single token.